# load_entry_point doesnt see other modules - "No module named" error

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have trouble with running my python app through script created by pip install. ModuleNotFoundError occurs for reasons which are hidden to me :/

```sh
#jsdc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jsdc", line 6, in <module>
    from src.sensor_data_collector import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/src/sensor_data_collector.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gatherer import Gatherer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gatherer'
```

Everything runs smoothly when I run the app directly through entry point:

```sh
python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/src/sensor_data_collector.py
```

Project setup.py:

```py
import os
import pathlib
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install

HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()


def run(self):
    install.run(self)
    current_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    create_service_script_path = os.path.join(current_dir_path, 'install_scripts', 'create_service.sh')
    subprocess.check_output([create_service_script_path])


setup(
    name="jacfal-sensor-data-collector",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="Collects data from iot sensors and sent them to defined target",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Jacfal/SensorDataCollector",
    author="Jacfal",
    author_email="jacfal.tech@protonmail.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["jsdc=src.sensor_data_collector:main", ]
    },
)
```

Project file structure:

```
.
├── install_scripts
│   └── create_service.sh
├── install.sh
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── configuration.py
│   ├── config.yml
│   ├── event.py
│   ├── gatherer.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── sensor_helpers.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── sensor_data_collector.py
│   ├── sensor.py
│   ├── sensors
│   │   ├── dummy_sensor.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── targets
│   │   ├── influxdb_target.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── log_target.py
│   └── target_system.py
└── tests
```

I am working with the setup.py for the first time, so I will be glad for any help or advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something missing from the picture. You do not seem to have a top-level package, and your distribution was built as if to have `src` as the top level package name - try  `import src.gatherer` and it would "work".

Of course the proper fix is to have a *proper top level package* which means you need to make a directory *inside* `src` (`sensor_data_collector` perhaps?) and move all the files into *that* directory; and use `find_packages('src')`. Then you need to prefix all the imports with this.

Comment: You are right. It works fine when I paste 'src' as a top level package before the module. So I will do a little refactoring. Thanks for your help.